# Avoid hyphenation in "2-D"

Tags: hyphenation

How can I avoid hyphenation in words such as "2-D"? `\hyphenation{}` is not working since the dash is not a letter.

Comment: [this forum](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=5673) has another answer which works for me: `\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}`. Is this 'cleaner' than introducing a box?

Answer (score 36):

Write it inside a box, like this: `\mbox{2-D}`

Comment: It's better to use `\mbox` and I have corrected the answer; try using `\hbox{2-D}` as the first object in a paragraph and you'll see why `\mbox` is preferable.

Comment: To avoid the problem you mention I'd use $\hbox{2-D}$ instead. That way the solution works with plain TeX too.

Comment: Why not `\mbox{-}` as seen [in mhp's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23146)?

Answer (score 18):

To expand on Herbert's answer, here's a list of `babel` languages that support `"~` for an unbreakable hyphen:

`danish`, `dutch`, `german` and `ngerman`, `icelandic`, `norsk`, `swedish`, `bulgarian`, `slovak`, `russian` and `ukrainian`.

Comment: Would there be a way to use the nonbreaking hyphen `"~` in, say english?

Comment: @Seamus: Well, of course that's possible by making `"` active, but that might have other bad side effects.

Comment: @Seamus: `\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}`

Comment: @Seamus: See [babel: Adding `ngerman`s language shorthands to `english` as the main document language](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27198)

Answer (score 7):

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand\twoD{\mbox{2-D}\xspace}
```

`\twoD and 2"~D` ...: the latter with `babel` if the language supports `"~`

And an example with several languages and extended shorthands

```
\documentclass[french,english,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\textwidth=5cm
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\selectlanguage{english}

foo bar foo bar foo foobar and-another word

foo bar foo bar foo foobar and"~another word

\selectlanguage{french}
foo bar foo bar foo foobar and"~another word

\selectlanguage{english}\shorthandoff{"}
foo bar foo bar foo foobar and"~another word

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbert: I don't understand this answer. Are you saying that `3"~D` works always, but `2"~D` only with babel? I tried it, and only got the `"~` working with `german`.

Comment: @Hendrik: it is an example ... `7"~D, 1"~D,...` I don't know what babel defines for every language. At least it works for ngerman/german ...

Comment: @Herbert: Still I think your answer is very confusing. Can you please make it clearer that you're suggesting two completely different solutions, and indicate what is needed to make them work?

Comment: @Hendrik. it is not confusing ...

Comment: @Herbert: It took me 5 minutes to figure out what you mean and what is needed to make `"~` work. And I only managed using the knowledge that you're German!

Comment: @Herbert: Maybe the upvotes to my comments convince you?

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, now that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks also for the example code! Now I see how it works.

Answer (score 5):

With Xe(La)TeX, at least, you could also use the "non-breaking hyphen" (U+2011), given a font which contains the glyph.

Comment: Unfortunately not: XeTeX doesn't enforce Unicode properties such as non-breakable by default.  There have been several discussions about characters like this on the XeTeX mailing-list, but none of them has lead to an improvement of the situation (for the moment).

Comment: @Arthur: should it not work anyway? U+2011 is not an `<explicit hyphen>` so unless there is an actual pattern for U+2011, there should not be any hyphenation

Comment: Yes indeed, in that particular case; but I wanted to point out that you can't expect from XeTeX to behave the right way out of the box with these characters: you also run the risk that the font you use doesn't have that character, for example (it's apparently quite common for the companion character U+2010 -- but I only speak from hearsay here).

Comment: Why do I get flak for this? Like @Taco pointed out, there is no way `2‑D` (you can copy that if you don't know how to produce it) is going to get hyphenated, because there are **no patterns** for `2<<unicode-char-for-non-breaking-hyphen>>d` in *any language*!

Comment: @morbusg: I'm not sure why it was voted down. Arthur's comment about it not appearing in a font was a reasonable one, but this seems like a good answer to me. I've upvoted it.

Comment: @morbusg: I didn't downvote your answer, but I didn't upvote it either, as it doesn't seem to me like useful advice in practice (because of the "given a font which contains the glyph" caveat -- although it is of course perfectly logically correct!)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this general method help.

First, define a macro who insert a non-breaking hyphen after some (math) stuff, but allowed hyphenation in the word after :

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\tiret}{\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}}
```

Then define the macro twoD :

```
\newcommand{\twoD}{\(2\)\tiret D\xspace}
```

the text-mode version works too :

```
\newcommand{\twoD}{2\tiret D\xspace}
```

The advantage of this method is if you want a hyphen follow by a long word, by ex. 2-cyclotetrabenzene.

P.S. I apologize for my poor english

Answer (score 4):

If your editor supports Unicode and the font used by it includes the non-breaking hyphen (this is, e.g., the case for Emacs under current Debian Linux) you can try the following:

Load the `inputenc` or `inputenx` package:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Define a macro yielding a non-breaking hyphen, e.g.:

```
\newcommand*{\nobreakhyphen}{\mbox{-}}
```

or:

```
\newcommand*{\nobreakhyphen}{\nobreak\mbox{-}\nobreak\hskip0pt}
```

Bind the corresponding Unicode character to `\nobreakhyphen`:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2011}{\nobreakhyphen}
```

Then, whenever you type the Unicode character U+2011 (using an adequate input method) you get a non-breaking hyphen, e.g.:

```
2‑D
```

Comment: See the answer from morbusg and its discussion.

Comment: @mhp: I tried both forms of `\nobreakhyphen` shown above, and both worked. Cool. But then I tried the second form (the one with `\nobreak`) without the `\mbox`, and it didn't work anymore, which puzzled me. So what does the `\nobreak` actually add here?

Answer (score 4):

Using XeLaTeX, and if you can input your non-breaking hyphen (U+2011) directly, the following elegant solution is available (courtesy of the XeTeX archives, post by Roland Kuhn, 2010.11.01):

> The non-breaking hyphen can also be made active and defined to yield
>   “\hbox{-}” (the box prevents the discretionary after the ASCII hyphen
>   from escaping, \nobreak does not help here):
>
> ```
> \catcode‑=\active
> \def‑{\hbox{-}}
> ```

You put the above two lines in your preamble, and then in your source you simply use the non-breaking hyphen as needed. Working like a charm here (TeXShop+MacTeX 2011), with big thanks to Roland.

Servus,
J

Comment: An almost equivalent way is to load the `newunicodechar` package and say `\newunicodechar{‑}{\mbox{-}}`. It's actually a bit more robust.

Comment: If by robust @egreg means the `\mbox`, then it's the same to stick a `\long` before the `\def`, and to have a `\leavevmode` before the `\hbox` (that is, if a par begins with a `-`; highly unlikely, but still). Although I'm not sure what good is the `\long` doing since the input is going into a `\hbox`. If you stick input starting with `\vbox`, it doesn't matter whether it's `\long` or not.

Comment: @morbusg No: the robustness I refer to would be obtained by prefixing `\def` with `\protected`. `\long` is relevant only for macros with arguments (and gives no robustness against expansions).

Comment: @egreg ah, so it's the `\newunicodechar`, then. Thanks.