# how to enforce correct hyphenation of "(near-)uniform" as "(near-)" + "uniform" instead of "(near-" +  ")uniform"?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

how to enforce correct hyphenation of `(near-)uniform` as `(near-)` `uniform` instead of `(near-` `)uniform`?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngermans-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-l

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\discretionary`. It takes three arguments:

```
\discretionary{at line end}{at next line begin}{if not hyphened}
```

In you case all arguments must be empty. I suggest define a new command for that, like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myhyph}{\discretionary{}{}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{1.5cm}
(near-)\myhyph uniform
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: discretionary]

The `{minipage}` is only used to get a narrow line in this example.

With

```
\newcommand{\nbhyph}{\mbox{-}}
```

You can also define a non breakable hyphen:

```
(near\nbhyph)\myhyph uniform
```

I’m sure on can use active characters to make the macros shorter.

Note that `babel` with `(n)german` defines several short hands for hyphenations. See the manual on page 81.

---

You may warp this in new macros to get a short access:

[Update: As egreg said it’s maybe easier to define `\newcommand{\sh}[1]{(#1\mbox{-})\discretionary{}{}{}}`. I changed it]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sh}[1]{% s = special, h = hyphen ...
    (#1\mbox{-})\discretionary{}{}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
   \sh{near}uniform
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: is there also a way to tell LaTeX to get this right automatically, i.e. without changing the text near "(near-)uniform"?

Comment: You should not call it a 'dash': "You can also define a non breakable **dash**:" since its a hyphen.

Comment: @Walter: I added a solution with command, but I guess you can’t tell TeX to do this automatically …

Comment: @tohecz: But how should I call it. A “non break hyphen” seems contradictory to me, since a hyphen always appears at line breaks.

Comment: @Walter: You can disable the breaks after the hyphen. See my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13296/how-to-prevent-linebreaks-after-hyphen-if-word-starts-with-hyphen. But you will still have to insert a breakpoint before "uniform".

Comment: I don't see any contradiction in 'non-breakable hyphen'. But I see a problem in calling `-` 'dash' while 'dash' is `--` or `---`.

Comment: And for example, in `2-year-old dog` you use hyphens and it's not at the line break...

Comment: @tohecz: OK. That makes sense, I’m no native speaker O:-)

Comment: No worries, I'm just used to wanting to have things clear :)

Comment: In german we differentiate between _Bindestrich_ (hyphen to combine words, as in your dog example) and _Trennstrich_ (hyphen to separate syllables at the end of a line). An for that I translated the first on with dash and only the second one with hyphen.

Comment: @Tobi Wouldn't it be easier `\newcommand{\sh}[1]{(#1\mbox{-})\discretionary{}{}{}}` and writing `\sh{near}uniform`?

Answer (score 8):

You could use the german shorthands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{1.5cm}
(near"~)""uniform
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd rather suggest `(near"~)""uni"-form`. `"~` to prevent hyphenation immediately after the dash, and `"-` to allow hyphenation for the rest of word.

Comment: Is there a way without using additional packages?

Comment: @Walter: Or my answer above ;-)

Comment: @lockstep The `"-` in uniform is not necessary. But I add the "~.

Comment: @Walter: Using babel (for hyphenation) is a good idea anyway. Also: if you don't like to load packages, don't use LaTeX. It is part of the LaTeX philosophy to have a rather small core and to activate additional features through packages. And at last: naturally you could define such shorthands yourself by copying the babel definitions.

Comment: Adding `\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{")}{\mbox{-})\hskip\z@skip}` allows for `(near")uniform`, which might be more appealing.