# Hyphen going into margin

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation

I have the following issue with a hyphen going into the margin:

[image: output]

As you can see, the `Spatio-Temporal` word has crossed the margin. How can I fix it in LaTeX? I am using the TeX template at [www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/8400/HQuick_cv.tex](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/8400/HQuick_cv.tex).

Comment: You can use a local hyphenation suggestion: `Spatio-Tem\-poral` where `\-` denotes the hyphenation points. See [LaTeX not hyphenating properly, text running off page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28136/5764).

Comment: by default latex doesn't hyphenate explicitly hyphenated words (but the referenced file does not have the phrase you show in the image) babel gives a "- shortkut to a hyphen that does allow the word to be further hyphenated (or use `-\hspace{0pt}Temporal`

Answer (score 3):

With `babel`, some languages:

```
Spatio"=Temporal
```

With `babel`, some other languages:

```
Spatio"-Temporal
```

with `babel` 3.9+:

```
Spatio\babelhyphen{hard}Temporal
```

with `hyphenat`:

```
Spatio\hyp{}Temporal
```

otherwise:

```
Spatio-\hspace{0pt}Temporal
```

### Overview of hyphens and hyphenation points

These always show a (hard) hyphen:

- `-` restrict to these hyphenation points (U+002D / U+2010)

  - `\babelhyphen*{hard}`
- `"=` allows other hyphenation points

  - `\babelhyphen{hard}`
  - `\nobreak\-\nobreak\hskip\z@skip`
  - `\hyp{}` from the `hyphenat` [package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28138/41085):
    `\leavevmode\nobreak\hskip\z@skip-\discretionary{}{}{}\nobreak\hskip\z@skip`
- `"~` not a valid hyphenation point, usually at the [beginning or end of a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13296/how-to-prevent-linebreaks-after-hyphen-if-word-starts-with-hyphen) (NBHY U+2011)

  - `\babelhyphen*{nobreak}`, possibly `\babelhyphen{nobreak}` (-suffix) or `\babelhyphen{hard}` (prefix-)
  - `\leavevmode\hbox{-}`

These only show a (soft) hyphen at the end of a line:

- `\-` restrict to these hyphenation points (~ SHY U+00AD), but [`\IUPAC`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28146/41085)

  - `\babelhyphen*{soft}`
- `"-` allows other hyphenation points (~ SHY U+00AD)

  - `\babelhyphen{soft}`
  - `\penalty\@M-\hskip\z@skip`
  - `-\hspace{0pt}`
- `"|` suppresses ligation (ZWNJ U+200C)

  - `\babelhyphen{}`
  - `\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}\allowhyphens`
  - `\/`

This never shows a hyphen:

- `""` usually in combination with another hyphen (ZWSP U+200B)

  - `\babelhyphen{empty}`
  - `\hskip\z@skip`

([Note](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxabbrv): `\@M` = 10000, `z@skip` = 0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt; some macros have been expanded)

### Using shorthands in English

The ones beginning with `"` are available in `german` variants of the `babel` package by default, other `ldf` files may deviate, e.g. `"-` may be a hard hyphen elsewhere. They can be [enabled for English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28143/41085) like this:

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
```

Since `babel` version 3.9 [you can also do](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13297/41085):

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
￼￼￼\useshorthands*{"}
\defineshorthand{"-}{\babelhyphen{hard}}
```

Comment: I'm confused by the use of `\nobreak\-\nobreak\hskip\z@skip`, could you explain why we need a glue after the penalty `\nobreak`?

Comment: @TuffContender I don’t remember where that code came from, it’s probably Babel’s `\babelhyphen{hard}` (as it was 2 years ago).

Comment: Thank you for response, and I just found the answer in _TeXbook_  that TeX only starts hyphenation with word immediately following a glue.