# Prevent linebreak if word begins with hyphen

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, linguistics

Words beginning with hyphens such as suffixes in linguistic texts can break right after the hyphen which is undesirable.

To prevent this I know I could do `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` or what the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13296/how-to-prevent-linebreaks-after-hyphen-if-word-starts-with-hyphen) suggest, but I was wondering if anyone has come up with a solution that would automatically prevent linebreaks if preceded by a space or at the beginning of line, without having to use a special command and without also preventing compounds-with-hyphens to break?

Comment: would markup such as `\?ing` rather than `-ing` be acceptable? with `\def\?{\mbox{-}}` as a non-breakable hyphen?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmm, I was hoping there was some automated solution, since I'd have to do a bunch of seach&replace in the the document, and also since I have a setup where I export the text also to word (for advisor comments) where I then would have to do a reverse search&replace again ...

Comment: I know you asked not to use a special command, but they come with additional benefits: I use macros like `\newcommand{\form}[1]{\mbox{\emph{#1}}}` for in-line linguistic forms and `\newcommand{\uf}[1]{\mbox{/#1/}}` for underlying forms. The `\mbox` prevents the line breaking problem and then you can also tweak the formatting in the command definition depending on publishers' style guides.

Comment: `\newcommand{\suffix}[1]{\mbox{#1}}` and `\suffix{-ing}` will solve the issue.

Comment: @JasonZentz egreg These are great hints, thank you, and I recognize the merit of defining a separate command. Nonetheless I'm still curious whether there is any way to achieve this without a separate command.