# babel: Adding ngerman' s language shorthands to english as the main document language

Tags: languages, hyphenation, babel, shorthands

The `(n)german` language option of the [babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) package provides various shorthands related to hyphenation, e.g. `"-`: *"an explicit hyphen sign, allowing hyphenation in the
rest of the word"* (manual, section 22). At least some of these shorthands are also useful for English texts -- e.g., typing `zoning-facil"-itated` results in the following legal breakpoints (assuming English hyphenation patterns): `zoning-facil-i-tated`. (Note: hyphenation before `"-` is disabled in this case because of the explicit hyphen after "zoning".)

When using `ngerman` as the main document language and switching to `english` within the document body, `\addto` allows to carry over language shorthands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

Adding \textsf{ngerman} language shorthands to \textsf{english}: zoning-facil"-itated.

\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work with `english` as the main document language (and `ngerman` still specified as additional option):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}

Adding \textsf{ngerman} language shorthands to \textsf{english}: zoning-facil"-itated.

\end{document}
```

How can I add `ngerman`s language shorthands to `english` while using `english` as the main document language?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\begin{document}

\minipage{1cm}\hrulefill

\hspace{0pt}zoning-facilitated

\hspace{0pt}zoning"=facil"-itated
\endminipage
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `lualatex` you do not need the `\hspace{0pt}` (LuaTeX hyphenates the first word of a paragraph, which TeX doesn't)

Comment: Okay, that's the new winner. :-)

Comment: Funny thing: It fails if you load `babel` with `\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}` in combination with `hyperref`'s `\autoref`.

Comment: Give an example!

Comment: @Herbert would have been great, if you'd pinged me. Now I saw it just now by chance and don't remember the use case where I encountered this...

Answer (score 12):

One has to define the language specific shorthands; I've left only the hyphenation related ones:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\initiate@active@char{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{english}\bbl@activate{"}}
\addto\noextrasenglish{\bbl@deactivate{"}}
\declare@shorthand{english}{"-}{\nobreak\-\bbl@allowhyphens}
\declare@shorthand{english}{"|}{%
  \textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}%
              \allowhyphens}{}}
\declare@shorthand{english}{""}{\hskip\z@skip}
\declare@shorthand{english}{"~}{\textormath{\leavevmode\hbox{-}}{-}}
\declare@shorthand{english}{"=}{\penalty\@M-\hskip\z@skip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hsize=3pt

\hskip0pt zoning-facilitated

\hskip0pt zoning-facil"-itated

\end{document}
```

It's quite easy also to import the `ngerman` shorthands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\initiate@active@char{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}\bbl@activate{"}}
\addto\noextrasenglish{\bbl@deactivate{"}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hsize=3pt

\hskip0pt zoning-facilitated

\hskip0pt zoning-facil"-itated

\end{document}
```

Of course, `ngerman` has to be loaded, otherwise the shorthands would not be known; so the first alternative seems better.

Comment: +1 -- however, explicitly cloning `ngerman`s shorthand definitions is a somewhat "brute-force" solution. Let's see if someone figures out a solution based on the fact that my first example works.

Comment: I've added how to import the `ngerman` shorthands.

Comment: Sorry for revoking my (premature) acceptance, but Herbert's answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Neat; but I believe that the "brute force" approach has its merits

Comment: You still have my upvote. :-)

Comment: I'm happy to upvote as well. :-)