# Hyphenation problem with --- versus \textemdash

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

While investigating problems with hyphenation and em-dashes, I came across this:

```
a piece---perhaps an installation---, involving structural feedback
```

The document class is `article`. The problem was that `installation` was not hyphenated, and an overfull line was produced, with `installation---` moving over the right margin, and the next line beginning with the comma.

Now I happened to try this, and it fixed the problem:

```
a piece---perhaps an installation\textemdash, involving structural feedback
```

properly breaking the line such as

```
...instal-
lation---, involving...
```

This seems counter-intuitive to me, and I really prefer to see the triple hyphens in my source code, much more readable. Is there a way to fix this problem?

---

It looks clearly like a latex error to me, because [standard usage of em-dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash) states: "According to most American sources [...] and some British sources [...], an em dash should always be set closed, meaning it should not be surrounded by spaces."

Comment: Try your original construction with `\sloppy`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have, at least, three possible options:

1. Use `\textemdash` instead of `---`. You already mentioned this in your question and it seems counter-intuitive for you.
2. Manually declare the valid hyphenation points for the word preceding the `---`.
3. Load the `babel` package and use `\allowhyphens---`. I think this approach will give you something closer to what you want since you could declare some character as active (`"` for example) and define a command `"---` to be `\allowhyphens---`; you then will write `"---` to get an em-dash allowing hyphenation for the preceding word (this approach was used by Javier Bezos in his implementation of a similar shorthand in the `spanish` module for `babel`).

Here's some code showing the problem and the three alternatives I mentioned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

some filler text to illustrate the problem here's a piece---perhaps an installation---, involving structural feedback

some filler text to illustrate the problem here's a piece---perhaps an installation\textemdash, involving structural feedback

some filler text to illustrate the problem here's a piece---perhaps an installation\allowhyphens---, involving structural feedback

some filler text to illustrate the problem here's a piece---perhaps an in\-stal\-la\-tion---, involving structural feedback

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's some code that could be used to implement my suggestion in the third numeral above :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\catcode`"=13
\def"-{\allowhyphens-}

\begin{document}

some filler text to illustrate the problem here's a piece---perhaps an installation---, involving structural feedback

some filler text to illustrate the problem here's a piece---perhaps an installation"---, involving structural feedback

\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet another alternative, taken from [this answer by Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27202/3954) to [babel: Adding ngerman' s language shorthands to english as the main document language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27198/3954) (thanks to **egreg** for pointing out this question) is to use the `spanish` modulo as a secondary language and use its already existing shorthand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{spanish}}

\begin{document}

some filler text to illustrate the problem here's a piece---perhaps an installation---, involving structural feedback

some filler text to illustrate the problem here's a piece---perhaps an installation"---, involving structural feedback

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But that's even more horrible than falling back to `\textemdash`, and I will need to hyphenate each word preceding an em-dash, just in case it ends up at a line end. To me this is clearly a latex error (see my addendum about common em-dash use).

Comment: @EmitTaste you're right. I've updated my answer now showing another possible solution.

Answer (score 11):

The reason why `installation---` doesn't allow TeX to hyphenate the word is explained in the TeXbook (p. 95):

> The most common case of a discretionary break is a simple discretionary hyphen
>
> ```
> \discretionary{-}{}{}
> ```
>
> for which TeX accepts the abbreviation ‘`\-`’. The next most common case is
>
> ```
> \discretionary{}{}{}
> ```
>
> (an “empty discretionary”), which TeX automatically inserts after ‘`-`’ and after every ligature that ends with ‘`-`’. In the case of plain TeX, empty discretionaries are therefore inserted after hyphens and dashes. (Each font has an associated `\hyphenchar`, which we can assume for simplicity is equal to ‘`-`’.)

Conversely, LaTeX defines

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textemdash}{OT1}{124}
```

or, with the T1 encoding,

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textemdash}{T1}{22}
```

so that the command `\textemdash` directly selects a character, without passing through the ligature mechanism, so that no empty discretionary is inserted.

In my opinion you *should* use `---`, manually correcting possible bad breaks and deciding, in tough situations, whether hyphenating the word next to the dash is the lesser evil.

Answer (score 11):

Another solution, besides the ones already mentioned in the other answers, consists of inserting `\nobreak\hskip0pt` between `installation` and `---`. That way, TeX can hyphenate the word "installation", but there won't be line break right between `tion` and the em-dash.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of the traditional `---` ligature, I use the Unicode character `—`, which is equivalent to `\textemdash`. In my opinion, there should be no line break at the em dash, but hyphenation within the adjacent words seems acceptable to me. To achieve this, I patch `\textemdash` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

\apptocmd{\textemdash}{%
  \nobreak\hskip\z@skip%
}{%
}{%
}

\robustify\textemdash

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showhyphens{hyphenation—hyphenation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Undefined control sequence.
`\textemdash ...\PD1\textemdash \nobreak \hskip \z 
                                                  @skip`

Comment: @AT: you forgot `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother`.

Comment: No I didn't, it's above @ilya-zakharevich

Comment: @AT: I’m confused: “what is above” is written by a different person.  Just in case, I double-checked: The message you quote appears indeed when one removes `\makeatletter`.

Answer (score 2):

In case of strange behavior or foreign languages, you can manually instruct LaTeX to hyphenate your word like this

```
in\-stal\-la\-tion
```

`\-` shows a possible hyphen.

Comment: It's not a problem of the dictionary. If I don't have the em-dash, it properly breaks e.g. at `instal\-lation` with english babel and `install\-ation` with UKenglish (the one I use now).