# Redefining the emdash so as to allow hyphenation

Tags: luatex, punctuation, hyphenation

OK, so I use the emdash as follows: `someword---anotherword`, but the problem is this prevents hyphenation of both words around the dash. I can fix this by replacing `---` with `\textemdash`, but I was wondering, is there any way to redefine the `---` "command" with `\textemdash`?

I use LuaTeX. Related to this issue issue I've found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56657/hyphenation-problem-with-versus-textemdash) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34721/why-do-hyphenated-words-cause-margin-violations-and-how-can-i-prevent-it), but neither provides an acceptable solution...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just my opinion, but it would seem to me a bit ugly to have a hyphen in a word that also adjoins an em-dash.

Comment: True, but having an overlong paragraph manages to be even uglier, so... :-)

Comment: Assuming this does not happen too much you could always fix it ad hoc with optional hyphens, like so: `some\-word---another\-word`.  But clearly that's not the general solution you seek.

Comment: Or type `someword{}---{}anotherword`, but again not general...

Comment: Or investigate the `extdash` package.  The reason this is hard is that the --- is defined as a ligature deep down in the TeX fonts rather than as a macro.

Comment: @Thruston this is no longer correct with Luatex which OP is asking a solution for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `extdash` package does what you want, but you have to type `\---` instead of `---`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
\begin{document}
someword\---anotherword
\end{document}
```

See also this [longer discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56657/hyphenation-problem-with-versus-textemdash) elsewhere on TeXSE.

Comment: This almost right, except for the fact that it adds a small amount of whitespace before and after the dash. I've looked at the package's documentation, but it doesn't mention a way to alter this behaviour. Is there one?

Comment: I don't know `extdash` that well, but I'll add a pointer to another question and answer with a longer discussion on the same topic.

Comment: I actually had already seen that discussion, but had forgotten about it when got myself to type this question. It did not help me much, I'm afraid. Anyway, given that your answer was closest to what I wanted, I'll mark it is as the right one.

Answer (score 5):

ConTeXt MkIV supports automatic hyphenation of [compound words](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Compound_words) by setting

```
\setbreakpoints[compound]
```

Here is an example

```
\setbreakpoints[compound]
\starttext
 \startframedtext[width=5cm]
  Just some random text to see if someword---anotherword hyphenates or not.
\stopframedtext
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: And can this somehow be done in LuaLaTeX, too?

Comment: @Gaussler: I am sure that it should be possible to port the ConTeXt code to LaTeX. But I am not familiar with LaTeX internals. It may be better to ask that as a separate question to get the attention of LaTeX experts.