# LaTeX allows line break between concluding em-dash and comma before a new sub clause begins

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation

I am surprised by LaTeX putting a comma which follows an em-dash on a new line when the previous line is flushed. My intuition and sense of style tells me that they should never be separated. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=38mm, inner=40mm, outer=24mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\begin{document}

Foo bar. The erosion responsible for ‘residuals’ is less related to the material process of 
creation---e.g., rewriting in the sense of Mondrian or blurring the edges in the sense of 
Rothko---, but to the double nature of time\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why isn't the second line ending with em-dash *and* comma? Is this the correct way you would break lines in (British) English?

Comment: To begin with, one should ask whether “—,” is good style.

Comment: [em-dash insertions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em-dash#Em_dash) are integral part of my style. So yes, one can ask that question, but if we accept this possibility, why is the line break so odd?

Comment: Any ligature ending with a hyphen `-` inserts a discretionary break. Use `\textemdash,` which doesn't suffer from the problem. I'd simply avoid the case by not thinking to it in the first place. But the document is yours.

Comment: Here is an [interesting answer](http://www.amnation.com/vfr/archives/021137.html) to whether "---," is good style. First of all, it confirms my feel that em-dash and comma are complementary elements and can occur together. On the other hand, the examples place the comma _before_ the insertion. Can someone with native English confirm whether this is the preferred punctuation? My German genes want me to put the comma after the insertion...

Comment: @EmitTaste In the given sntence, "but" should be "than" and no comma is required in the constriction "less ... than ...". Thus, only the emdashes are required. I think of a comma as a point where a pause would be introduced in speaking, so even if a grammatical consruction would seem to require a comma, the pause already introduced by the emdash would remove the need for a comma. Visually, the emdash-comma comination is jarring to my Germanic/American/English sensibilities. I would rewrite the sentence in preference to using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're being very unlucky, since a comma is really a thin character. You'll probably avoid all those cases by loading `microtype`.

However, if you want to be on the safe side, type `\textemdash,` which will not add a discretionary break, as explained in answers to [Hyphenation problem with --- versus \textemdash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56657/hyphenation-problem-with-versus-textemdash)

The output with `microtype`, with no change in the input, is the same as with `\textemdash,`; of course, `microtype` has other benefits.

[image]