# In table cell, how to break long words after “::” or “_”?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable

I have a software program can generate tables which may be very long and may contains words with many letters,so i use `longtabu` package. Some words may look like this:

> AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDDDD_CC
>
> aaa::Asldfjasldfjlasdfjasld

So I use `\allowbreak\_`   and   `\allowbreak\::` to break the long words in certain table cell. **But the problem is, if the word after underscore or colon is too long, it can not be breaked**. Longtabu can break long words, but not words after underscore or colon... And these long words are generated by software program, I can not add any break by hand.

So how to break it? Below is the code and pdf.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{dd}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a story \hyperlink{ABCDoABCoABCDoABCDDoABBoE}{alsdfas\_alsdjfa\_lasdkfjal\_alsdkfj}

\subsection{asdf asdfasf asdfasd}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ] |>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ] | >{\scriptsize}X[1 , p ]| >{\footnotesize}X[2 , p ]|>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ]|>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ]|}

\caption{asdf asfas}\\

\hline

\textbf{aaaaaa;\newline asdfasd} & \textbf{asdfasdf;\newline asdfasdf;\newline asdfasdf;\newline asdfa;\newline asdfasdfasfasfasdf\newline} & \footnotesize\textbf{asdfasdfas} & \textbf{asdfasdfs} & \textbf{asdfasdf;\newline asdfasdfasdf asdf asdfas} & \textbf{asdfasdfasd} \\

\hline

\hypertarget{ABCDoABCoABCDoABCDDoABBoE}{ABCD\allowbreak\_ABC\allowbreak\_ABBVASDFASDDDD\allowbreak\_ABC\allowbreak\_ABC\allowbreak    \_A}&&Caa:: CaaaaaaaBddddd\allowbreak::EabadfkajdlEadlsfjaDalsdfjalsdf
&&&\\\hline 

\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this a similar question like this, from your obviously 2nd account: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197958/how-to-break-lines-in-a-cell-of-table-a-very-long-word-contains-or?

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but if you have two accounts please ask the StackExchange staff to do a merge

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The reason I write it again, because you said i need post a code. Now i post it here, the old question you can delete it.

Comment: @postit: The *annoying* thing is, that you continously use two accounts ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, because I changed the computer, then the account is changed(eventhough the same name), which i did not expect it

Comment: @postit: How about work as a registered user? ;-)

Comment: @ I registered by my hotmail, but now i cannot log into hotmail...

Comment: an answer to the question [Help on dealing with items divided with slash[(http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121955/579) gives a method for allowing hyphenation in a word following a slash.  this technique might be adapted to a situation where a word is preceded by an underscore or double colon.

Comment: @postit Please register with an e-mail you can access then contact the staff and get them to merge all of your accounts together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make TeX think it is starting a new word after these breaks so that allows hyphenation of the following part.  `\hspace{0pt}` will accomplish such a break.  It is best to collect your code for this in to custom commands for the behaviour you wish to allow at the given punctuation mark:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{dd}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\uscbr}{\allowbreak\_\allowbreak\hspace{0pt}}
\newcommand{\ccbr}{\allowbreak::\hspace{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a story
\hyperlink{ABCDoABCoABCDoABCDDoABBoE}{alsdfas\_alsdjfa\_lasdkfjal\_alsdkfj}

\subsection{asdf asdfasf asdfasd}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ] |>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ] | >{\scriptsize}X[1 , p ]| >{\footnotesize}X[2 , p ]|>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ]|>{\footnotesize}X[1 , p ]|}

\caption{asdf asfas}\\

\hline

\textbf{aaaaaa;\newline asdfasd} & \textbf{asdfasdf;\newline asdfasdf;\newline asdfasdf;\newline asdfa;\newline asdfasdfasfasfasdf\newline} & \footnotesize\textbf{asdfasdfas} & \textbf{asdfasdfs} & \textbf{asdfasdf;\newline asdfasdfasdf asdf asdfas} & \textbf{asdfasdfasd} \\

\hline

\hypertarget{ABCDoABCoABCDoABCDDoABBoE}{ABCD\uscbr ABC\uscbr
ABBVASDFASDDDD\uscbr ABC\uscbr ABC\uscbr A}&&Caa:: CaaaaaaaBddddd\ccbr
EabadfkajdlEadlsfjaDalsdfjalsdf 
&&&\\\hline 

\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```