# Paragraph alignment problem when the line ended with a 2 words being separated by a "/"

Tags: vertical-alignment

At the end of one of my sentence 2 words are separated by a "/". The line is not justified. Why? How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter % <-Added code from here
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
 \let\@oddhead\@empty
 \let\@evenhead\@empty
 \def\@oddfoot{}%
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\keyword}{\textit}{}{}{}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

\begin{document} 
With all of good/bad on the one side and versions of reductionism/non-reductionism on the other, I recently dealt with the same task, so here I present my solution: I defined a new columntype Y to center the cells in a tabularx environment. I recently dealt with the same task, so here I present my solution: I defined a new columntype Y to center the cells in a tabularx environment. I recently dealt with the same task, so here I present my solution: I defined a new columntype Y to center the cells in a tabularx environment. I recently dealt with the same task, so here I present my solution: I defined a new columntype Y to center the cells in a tabularx environment. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `non-reductionism` with `non-\hspace{0pt}reductionism`? (What you're encountering is that TeX is programmed, by default, not to hyphenate a word that already contains a hyphen character.)

Comment: @Mico Just did that. Didn't work.

Comment: this might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121957/579

Comment: @user157323 - Please see the answer I just posted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - For the paragraph provided by the OP, the presence of the "slash" characters doesn't actually pose a problem. Instead, it's the presence of the `-` character in the word "non-reductionism".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX is programmed, by default, *never* to hyphenate words which already contain hyphens. In the example you gave, the problem word is `non-reductionism`, as may be verified in the first paragraph of the screenshot shown below. The result is a massively overfull line.

One way to override is to insert the directive `\hspace{0pt}` immediately after the hyphen character, i.e., to write the word as `non-\hspace{0pt}reductionism`. Check out the middle paragraph for the resulting look.

At least for the paragraph you provided, the presence of a `/` ("slash") character between `reductionism` and `non-reductionism` is actually irrelevant, as may be verified by comparing the middle and bottom paragraphs below; the only difference is in the bottom paragraphs, both `/` characters were replaced by the macro `\slash`.

[image]

If don't like the look of a word that contains two hyphenation characters (one of them being at the end of a line), the only remedy that's left is to rewrite the paragraph suitably.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
% (I've retained only the bare essentials...)
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{times}
\hyphenation{non-re-duc-tion-ism}

\begin{document} 
With all of good/bad on the one side and versions of 
reductionism/non-reductionism on the other, I recently 
dealt with the same task, so here I present my solution: 
I defined a new columntype\dots

\medskip
With all of good/bad on the one side and versions of 
reductionism/non-\hspace{0pt}reductionism on the other, 
I recently dealt with the same task, so here I present 
my solution: I defined a new columntype\dots

\medskip
With all of good\slash bad on the one side and versions of 
reductionism\slash non-\hspace{0pt}reductionism on the other, 
I recently dealt with the same task, so here I present 
my solution: I defined a new columntype\dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a general command to prevent this issue everywhere there is a hyphen?

Comment: @user157323 - Please clarify what you mean by "this issue". (My answer touched on several issues...)