# Hyphenate long acronyms

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, acronyms

I'm using the package `acronym` but I have a problem. I have a very long acronym "ADD1/SREBP1". I defined it like this:

```
\acro{srebp}[ADD1/\-SREBP1]{adipocyte determination-and differentiation-dependent
    factor 1/ste\-rol regulatory element binding protein 1}
```

But in the text it is not separated and it creates a badbox.
How can I fix this problem?

I add a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openright,draft]{book}

\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter 
\patchcmd\@acf{\hskip\z@}{}{}{}
\patchcmd\@acf{\hskip\z@}{}{}{}
\makeatother%this patch fixes white spaces after acronyms

\begin{document}

I cite the acronym first here \ac{srebp}. Then in the end of a row like this
but depends pf course on margins \ac{srebp}.

\begin{acronym}[AAAAAAA]
\acro{srebp}[ADD1\slash SREBP1]{adipocyte determination-and differentiation-dependent
    factor 1/ste\-rol regulatory element binding protein 1}

\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try `ADD1\slash SREBP1`

Comment: I tried both

        `ADD1\slash SREBP1`

and 

        `ADD1\slash\- SREBP1`

but they are not working...

Comment: Then please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: added. I found this in another question: 
`\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@acf{\AC@acl}{\AC@foo}{}{}
\patchcmd\@acf{\AC@acl}{\AC@foo}{}{}
\patchcmd\@acf{\AC@foo}{\hskip\z@\AC@acl}{}{}
\patchcmd\@acf{\AC@foo}{\hskip\z@\AC@acl}{}{}
\makeatother ` but i guess it's for the long part of the acronym. My problem is with the short one.

Comment: The code snippet you "found" needs the `etoolbox` package and will produce an error without it, as you could have found out by compiling the latest version of your MWE.

Comment: I have it in my thesis, just I forgot to add it to the MWE posted!

Comment: You should add some `\-` to `differentiation-dependent` as currently it is only allowed to hyphenate at the dash.  (Maybe it would be a good idea to add `ngerman`'s shorthands to `english`.)  Also I think that `determination-and` is missing a space.

Comment: @cgnieder Re:shorthands: The OP might be interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngerman-s-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-lan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine the internal macro `\AC@acs` so that it doesn't use `\mbox` (which prevents line breaks).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openright,draft]{book}

\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\AC@acs[1]{%
    \expandafter\AC@get\csname fn@#1\endcsname\@firstoftwo{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I cite the acronym first here \ac{srebp}. Then in the end of a row like
this but debpnds pf course on margins \ac{srebp}.

\begin{acronym}[AAAAAAA]
\acro{srebp}[ADD1\slash SREBP1]{adipocyte determination-and differentiation-dependent
    factor 1/ste\-rol regulatory element binding protein 1}

\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `\patchcmd\AC@acs{\mbox}{\@firstofone}{}{}` since `etoolbox` is used by the OP already.