# using csquotes' shorthands in English

Tags: punctuation, babel, csquotes, shorthands

Is there a special reason why `csquotes`' shorthands cannot be used in English text or am I overlooking something? The `\enquote` command works fine.

It's true that English style quotes are amongst the easiest to type in LaTeX, but `csquotes` would still be nice to use in English for multi-lingual documents, to differentiate between the closing quote and apostrophe, or to separate writing the text and deciding whether to use singe or double quotes..

I hoped [the answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngerman-s-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-lan) could work for quotes as well, but I couldn't get it working..

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[main=british, german, french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}

\begin{document}
"`Text in "`British"'"'\\
\enquote{enquote} \enquote*{enquote*}

\selectlanguage{german}%
"`Text auf "`Deutsch"'"'\\
\enquote{enquote} \enquote*{enquote*}

\selectlanguage{french}%
"`Texte en "`Fran\c{c}ais"'"'\\
\enquote{enquote} \enquote*{enquote*}
\end{document}
```

[image: quotetest]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried it once more and now it worked (also for American)...

```
\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
```

But I haven't gotten to the bottom of it. When I run this through `LuaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Scale=0.92]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[main=british,russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\defineshorthand{"`}{\openautoquote}
\defineshorthand{"'}{\closeautoquote}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{russian}}

\begin{document}
"`Text in "`British"'"'\par
\selectlanguage{russian}%
"`Текст на "`русском"' языке"'\par
\selectlanguage{british}%
"`Text in "`British"'"'\par
\enquote{enquoted text in \enquote*{British}}\par
\selectlanguage{ngerman}%
"`Text auf "`deutsch"'"'\par
\selectlanguage{british}%
"`Text in "`British"'"'\par
\end{document}
```

the British quotes don't always work:

[image: RussianWithLuaTeX]