# Why does adding shorthands to language extras no longer work?

Tags: babel, shorthands

It used to be that this worked:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=american,ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasamerican{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{document}
  Test"=Test
\end{document}
```

This is taken directly from the `babel` manual. We would expect to see `Test-Test` but instead we get `Test"=Test`.

What changed and how do I adapt?

<sup>This is on TeXlive 2014 with `babel` at `Version 3.9l 2014/09/25`.</sup>

Comment: I get identical (`Test"=Test`) results on TeXLive2013 and TeXLive2014.

Comment: Ah, now that the answer is there, "Related" points to [this identical problem with solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27202/3213).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the manual should point out shorthands must be activated for `american` too. The simplest way to do it is, in the preamble:

```
\useshorthands*{"}
```

That makes `"` active for the whole document. If it worked without this declaration, it was a bug, because `german` deactivates shorthands when changing to another language (it should, but perhaps in a former version it didn't -- just a guess).

Comment: That helps, thanks! According to the manual, there were some changes with `3.9a` but we never noticed with our `ngerman` material.