# Incompatibility between tikz-cd and language

Tags: babel, tikz-cd

Sorry for the bad English. I'm trying to use the `tikz-cd` package to make commutative diagrams. My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r, "x"] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The problem occurs when putting a name under the arrow, the syntax "x" is incompatible with the `brazil` option of the `babel` package. When exchanging `brazil` for `english` it works normally. I already tried using

```
\usepackage[main=brazil, english]{babel}, \usepackage[brazil, english]{babel} e  \usepackage[brazil, main=english]{babel}
```

But it did not work. I also tried to use

```
\usepackage[english, brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\setotherlanguages{english}
```

And finally

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```

However, it only works if I remove the option `brazil`

Comment: On my pc with Papeeria I have these errors: `Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. [\end{tikzcd}] /main.tex :7 Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete. [\end{tikzcd}] /main.tex :7 Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@addpath was complete. [\end{tikzcd}]
/main.tex :7 Missing \endcsname inserted. [\end{tikzcd}]
/main.tex :7 Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@splitter was complete. [\end{tikzcd}]
/main.tex :6 Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '"x\par ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. [I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.]`

Comment: Is exactly that error that appears to me using Texstudio

Comment: Use `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` -- this should remove the error and compile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [babel: Adding ngerman' s language shorthands to english as the main document language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngerman-s-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-lan)

Comment: @Saravanan How is this a duplicate of the linked question? The OP asks for disabling the `"` shorthand from `brazil` language, while the linked question asks for enabling it in `english`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *TikZ* `babel` library simplifies the interaction between the `babel` LaTeX package and *TikZ* itself, taking care of the catcodes etc. change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r, "x"] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Always vote your answers. Very very good. hiiiiiiii

Comment: I found a list with more than 50 library but did not contain this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues: The tikz `babel` is not very well known, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Now there isn't any errors.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, brazil]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{"}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r, "x"] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\shorthandon{"}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also the answer of Christian Hupfer is very good.

Comment: Yes, in the pgf manual indicates the use of the `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}`, but that did not solve my problem