# Error with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Compiling this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

%MATHEMATICS
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge]
F(X)   \arrow[r,"F(X)"]\arrow[d,"F(X)"]&F(X)\arrow[d,"F(X)"]\\
F(X)\arrow[r,"X^{{\mathcal D}}_{F(X),F(Y)}"]&F(X)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I got the error 'Undefined controll sequence \end{tikzcd}'. And the reuslt looks not good at all. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`.

Comment: It worked, thank you! But why do I have to do this?

Comment: Well, perhaps look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358844/121799) for more information. It has to do with the catcodes (I do not like this term, would prefer tigercodes ;-), i.e. the quotes become active and bla bla bla. Long story short: load the library and it works. ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments: adding `tikz` library `babel` solve the problem.