# Incompatibility between Tikz-cd and German language under Polyglossia

Tags: tikz-pgf, polyglossia, tikz-cd

The following MWE shows a incompatibility between `tikz-cd` and `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzcd}
     B \arrow{rr}{f} && C\\
    &A \arrow{ul}{\phi} \arrow[swap]{ru}{\psi}
  \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

I have seen a few solutions when the problems come from `babel` like this one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358837/incompatibility-between-tikz-cd-and-language), but the solution does not work for `polyglossia` under `xelatex`.

The error is:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"{f}"{}' and I am going t
o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Comment: works okay here. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: With recent MikTeX works fine.

Comment: I am running TeXLive 2018 on this machine. So it looks like it is the problem ...

Comment: Indeed, this has been fixed in TL 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `german` language file makes `"` active, and older `tikz-cd` don't expect that and break.  But if you just load `tikz-cd` before `polyglossia` (thus freezing `"` as catcode-12), your code will work.

`tikz-cd` diagrams also use lots of `"` in them, so if you'll use them you also need to make `"` an ordinary character there.  The `babel` Ti*k*Z library does that for you (loading the `babel` library is usually a good idea).

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz-cd} % Load before polyglossia
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % load to use " in pictures

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
   B \arrow{rr}{f} && C\\
  &A \arrow{ul}{\phi} \arrow[swap]{ru}{\psi}
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] & B \\
                                & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```