# How to prevent LaTeX from line-breaking a phrase?

Tags: line-breaking

How can I prevent LaTeX from putting line-breaks into a phrase?

I could replace dashes with [`"~`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9691/avoid-hyphenation-in-2-d) and spaces with non-breaking spaces, but I'm looking for a more general solution in case I need other characters in such phrases.

Comment: Put the phrase in a `mbox`

Comment: Thanks. Does it effect anything else that I should be aware of?

Comment: Inside a `\mbox` you can't use any linebreaks ;-)

Comment: The effect of `\mbox` is that it *freezes* the spaces, so they won't be stretched or shrinked along with the others on the same line.

Comment: @egreg: Than that's not what I'm looking for. The only effect I'm looking for is non-breaking; they should still be formatted nicely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Telling TeX not to break lines in long phrases will almost certainly produce bad breaks, with overfull or underfull lines. However, here's a possible hack.

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\def\phrase{\begin{otherlanguage*}{nohyphenation}%
  \dononbreakablespace
  \dononbreakablehyphen
  \dophrase}
\def\dophrase#1{#1\end{otherlanguage*}}

{\catcode`\ =\active
\gdef\dononbreakablespace{\catcode`\ =\active\def {\nobreakspace}}}
{\catcode`\-=\active
\gdef\dononbreakablehyphen{\catcode`-=\active\def-{\nobreakhyphen}}}
\def\nobreakhyphen{\hbox{-}\nobreak}
```

Here's an example:

```
Testo per vedere se gli spazi sono uniformi \phrase{anche in una %
\emph{phrase} che non deve essere spezzata neanche dove-si-potrebbe %
ma solo dopo}, quando finisce.
```

If you need also en-dashes or em-dashes it's more complicated. With **babel** we can use its `nohyphenation` feature. It's handy but not necessary, as the same effect can be obtained in different ways.

The definitions can be read as follows.

1. The macro `\phrase` will only have a "user level argument" that actually is an argument to `\dophrase`; the purpose of `\phrase` is to open a group and do some initializations, in particular to inhibit hyphenation.
2. `\dophrase` reads the argument and closes the `otherlanguage*` environment, so that also all the other assignments will be undone.
3. `\donobreakablespace` activates the space and makes it translate to `\nobreakspace`. See note below.
4. `\donobreakablehyphen` activates the hyphen so that it typesets a hyphen which is "masked" and will not be a permissible break point.

Note. In the argument of `\phrase` (actually of `\dophrase`) consecutive spaces *will not* be reduced to one and *will not* be ignored at the start of an input line. Moreover line breaks in the input will be admissible break points for TeX. Mask them with `%` (preceded by a space).

If using **babel** is not a choice, one can do with some changes

```
\def\phrase{\begingroup\phrasenohyphen
  \dononbreakablespace
  \dononbreakablehyphen
  \dophrase}
\makeatletter
\def\phrasenohyphen{%
  \language\@ifundefined{l@nohyphenation}{\@cclv}{\l@nohyphenation}}
\makeatother
\def\dophrase#1{#1\endgroup}
```

The other macros can be the same. The "no hyphenation" feature is obtained by choosing explicitly the "nohyphenation" pseudolanguage or, if it's not defined (which may be the case on some old distributions) by choosing `\language255` that is probably not defined (so TeX will use an empty set of hyphenation rules).

Comment: You code is very nice but you should also recommend the package [hyphenat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyphenat).

Comment: @Marco **hyphenat** doesn't provide an environment form of `\nohyphen`; moreover in the argument of `\nohyphen`, explicit hyphens *are* admissible break points, so there is not really much advantage in using it.

Comment: The point isn't the advantages or disadvantages. It is a further possibility ;-)  (You know what I meean?)

Comment: @Marco IMO it doesn't fit at all with the problem, which is mainly not to break at spaces.

Answer (score 11):

The `\mbox` command does the job.

Comment: I think maybe `\mbox` prevents internal glue from stretching or shrinking.