# create a non breaking environment

Tags: line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent LaTeX from line-breaking a phrase?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29257/how-to-prevent-latex-from-line-breaking-a-phrase)

I add names of persons into an index.
How can I prevent that there will be a line brake in the name?

```
\newcommand*{\person}[1]{#1\sindex[person]{#1}}
```

It would be nice if there is another solution then writing `~` in all names manually.

Comment: `\hbox{#1}` perhaps?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to prevent LaTeX from line-breaking a phrase?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29257/5764)