# How can I avoid using hyphen at the linebreak to separate a word?

Tags: hyphenation

I just cannot find how to avoid breaking a word with hyphen when the line breaks. For example:

> *How can I trans-*
>
> *late a word ?*

Wait reply.
Regards.

Comment: do you mean prevent one particular hyphenation or do you want to prevent hyphenation everywhere?

Comment: Single line-break prevention: [How to prevent LaTeX from line-breaking a phrase?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29257/5764)

Comment: this question is not at all clear.  it *could* mean that the string "trans- late" is in the file, having been cut and pasted from a pdf file that had a line break there.  please clarify what is meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\minipage{4.4cm}
some more words to trans-late

some more words to trans\hbox{-}late
\endminipage    
\end{document}
```