# Nonbreaking dash that allows hyphenation

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, babel

The `babel` package provides useful dash variants, e.g. `"~` for a non-breaking dash that forbids hyphenation in the parts, and `"=` for a breaking dash that allows hyphenation in the parts.

However, "words" like

```
$x$-Koordinaten
```

do not quite fit; we would not want to have the dash breaking, but we *would* want to allow hyphenation of "Koordinaten". Of course,

```
$x$"~Ko\-or\-di\-na\-ten
```

works but has to be specified locally, which we do not want to do either (favoring a global `\hyphenation{...}` setting).

Is it possible to achieve the above in a form that does not force us to specify hyphenation locally?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]

If there is not already a shortcut you can as below, or better as egreg points out in comments

```
\makeatletter
 \defineshorthand[ngerman]{"/}{\mbox{-}\bbl@allowhyphens}
\makeatother
```

Then use `"/`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\setlength\textwidth{5cm}
\newcommand\zz{-\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}}
\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X


aaaa aaaa aa $x$-Koordinaten

aaaa aaaa aaa $x$-Koordinaten

aaaa aaaa aaaa $x$-Koordinaten

aaaa aaaa aaaaa $x$-Koordinaten

===

aaaa aaaa aa $x$\zz Koordinaten

aaaa aaaa aaa $x$\zz Koordinaten

aaaa aaaa aaaa $x$\zz Koordinaten

aaaa aaaa aaaaa $x$\zz Koordinaten


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Raphael tex adds penalties that allow breaking after an explicit hyphen, the mbpx stops that.

Comment: @egreg and David, "/-solution is pretty nice, I used it for long time untill came to the project where xelatex is used. Babel-based solutions does not work there. What would you suggest for this case?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution straight from the user guide of the `amsmath` package. (To get this to work, the `amsmath` package has to be loaded.)

```
$x$\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}Koordinaten
```

If you find yourself typing this sequence a lot, you may want to create a macro along the following lines:

```
\newcommand{\nbdx}{$x$\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}} % "no-break dash with x"
```

and type `\nbdx Koordinaten` in the body of the text.

Comment: What is the difference between `\nobreakdash` and `\nolinebreak` (as [David uses](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136996/3213)), aside from the fact that `\nobreakdash` does not seem to work in a babel shorthand?

Comment: I'd say that the `\nobreakdash` method is independent of, rather than in conflict with, the `babel` shorthands. Assuming you've loaded `babel` with an option such as `ngerman`, LaTeX should have no problem finding breakpoints inside the word "Koordinaten".

Comment: @Raphael `\nobreakdash-` essentially does `\sbox0{-}\unhbox0` which is mostly equivalent to the `\mbox{-}` method because it just removes the boxing (and the hyphen character does not add a discretionary item any more).

Comment: @Mico Thank you! all other sollutions didn't worked. Maybe this solution will be found easyer if I add: cvlist and currvita package.

Answer (score 6):

### tl;dr

```
\newunicodechar{‑}{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\symbol{'177}}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

Then just use ‑ (U+2011) instead of - (U+002D) before the closing parenthesis. This means you can now write `(re‑)creation` or `(Web‑)Frameworks` or even `Entwicklungs‑, Test/QS‑, Staging‑ oder Produktivsystem` (yes, I got dash-comma working).

If this does not work for you, @dessert reports that a combination of this and [Dmitry’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283196/43807) works:

```
\newunicodechar{‑}{\babelhyphen{nobreak}}
```

Which one to use seems to depend on the version of `babel` you use, and how you use it.

### Backstory

I was looking for this as well, but as a more generic solution, and so far, the answers I found all do not satisfy me. I do have the german Babel package included, but `"~` just typeset a double-quote followed by a space for me (and, in fact, I think I prefer double quotes to render as quote characters).

I looked at Unicode, and ‑ `U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN` appears to be what I want. Apparently, Xe(La)TeX already supports this, but we use pdflatex (directly in one project, via maven-latex-plugin in another), so that was out.

This pointed me into the correct direction though: I [already knew about `\newunicodechar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159701/43807) so I thought I could just make U+2011 available. My first attempt was…

```
% does not work
\newunicodechar{‑}{-}
```

… to just define it to the hyphen, but it does not work like that. So, after reading some answers here, I tried…

```
% throws an error message
\newunicodechar{‑}{\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}}
```

… but `\nobreakdash` is not known, apparently. Finally, I tried…

```
% works for me, except commas
\newunicodechar{‑}{-\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

… and voilà, I can typeset “(Maschinen‑)Benutzernamen” without the ugly separation *and* the automatic hyphenation makes this into “(Maschinen-)Benut-⏎zernamen” which is just perfect. Even better, when copy/pasting from the PDF, you get an actual - `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS`, which makes things like `\texttt{<!‑‑}` to get `<!--` (for XML comments) work.

#### Update 2016-09-04: Commas

There was a problem though: `‑,` would still shove the stray comma onto the next line. The [explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268859/43807) has to do with us still using the `-` ASCII hyphen-minus in our macro expansion, to which Teχ (un‑)helpfully adds a discretionary break. However, this can be worked around if the current font has a T1 encoding (and not just OT1 or LY1), by temporarily switching to the T1 encoding variant of the current font and outputting the named character 127 (0x7F), which is exactly the same as the standard \hyphenchar 45 (0x2D).

```
% works for me
\newunicodechar{‑}{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\symbol{'177}}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

For the (custom TrueType) font I was using, this required [some hacking](https://evolvis.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=veraweb/veraweb.git;a=commitdiff;h=ed3bc31b06c6e5c834f2d0460304405422f5f177;hp=1512ba84120fe71274212a49a568b3e53ccf3651) due to [a ttf2tfm bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=836691); if you just want to make sure that your font’s T1 encoding has the correct glyph at the correct position, use this (and replace `museo` with your font name):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\xfonttable{T1}{museo}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

(Note: I merged my answers to several questions in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282420/43807) then copied it to these other questions, so don’t wonder if it shows up in three places.)