# How to print a warning sign (triangle with exclamation point)?

Tags: symbols, unicode

I am interested in including a triangle with an exclamation point (unicode #9888: ⚠) in a tex document. I've looked in the usual places (detexify, etc.) and not found this symbol. The document should be compilable with pdflatex and the source should have ASCII encoding. I already have a tikz version that I like reasonably well, given by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\warningsign}{\tikz[baseline=-.75ex] \node[shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, inner sep=0pt, draw, thick] {\textbf{!}};}
\begin{document}
\warningsign Warning
\end{document}
```

so I am also requiring that the answer be an actual character, or at least not done using graphics.

Comment: I usually use `{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{futs}\selectfont\char 66\relax}` for that symbol.

Comment: @Nicola Talbot: Works like a charm! Please add that as an answer so that I can upvote it (and accept it unless someone comes along with a deeper explanation).

Comment: You also have `\usepackage{bclogo}` and `\bcattention`.

Comment: this command is incompatible with \usepackage[french]{babel}

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The [`fourier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fourier) package provides `\warning`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\warning

\end{document}
```

I sometimes find that some of the `fourier` commands conflict with other packages I use, so if I only want this symbol I do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{futs}\selectfont\char 49\relax}

\end{document}
```

which is essentially what `\warning` does. This requires the `futs` font family which is provided with the `fourier` package, so the package must still be installed even though it's not actually being loaded.

If the `futs` font isn't available, the transcript will show the message:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/futs/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.
```

This means that the `cmr` font is being used instead, which has something else in the `\char 49` slot.

Comment: In the second example, note that you need to have the `fourier` package installed in your TeX Live distribution even though it is not explicitly loaded. Otherwise, you will just get a "B" instead of a warning triangle.

Comment: Thanks, @RadonRosborough. I was initially getting a "B". [at]NicolaTalbot could you add that to the answer as well?

Comment: I get this error in a Beamer document on Arch Linux: "mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for futr8r. mktexpk: perhaps futr8r is missing from the map file." Is there another package I have to install?

Comment: Be aware that the command is now called `\warning`. Also, character number has changed to 49. So for option two use `{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{futs}\selectfont\char 49\relax}`.

Answer (score 32):

A `\warning` symbol (previously `\danger`) is provided by the `fourier` package (see [`The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), table 475, page 177).

If you don't have the need for the complete `fourier` package, but you want to use that symbol, you can extract it and use in your document:

```
\newcommand*{\TakeFourierOrnament}[1]{{%
\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{futs}\selectfont\char#1}}
\newcommand*{\danger}{\TakeFourierOrnament{66}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\TakeFourierOrnament}[1]{{%
\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{futs}\selectfont\char#1}}
\newcommand*{\danger}{\TakeFourierOrnament{66}}

\begin{document}

\danger

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: In my installation of TeX Live 2022, this MWE produces a different output. It looks like the position of the symbol in the alphabet was changed at some point, nowadays it is 49 rather than 66...

Comment: I needed to use \TakeFourierOrnament{`1} (not 66). Whatever...

Answer (score 30):

A simple build assigned to the unicode symbol, so you can use `⚠` or `\Warning`:

[image: mWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand\Warning{%
 \makebox[1.4em][c]{%
 \makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{.1em}{\small!}}%
 \makebox[0pt][c]{\color{red}\Large$\bigtriangleup$}}}%

\newunicodechar{⚠}{\Warning}

\begin{document}

    Do⚠not⚠put your finger

    on the power plug.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! It's been a while since this answer, but I needed it today and it exactly suited me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Same thing but bigger: ```\newcommand\Warning{%
 \makebox[1.4em][c]{%
 \makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{.2em}{!}}%
 \makebox[1pt][c]{\color{red}\LARGE$\bigtriangleup$}}}%```

Comment: That's very good! The fourier package suggested in other answers messes up with some fonts.

Answer (score 25):

Here, I choose to build my own by overlaying a black, tiny `!` atop a red `$\triangle$`, and then scaling the result to a desired [optional] size

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\dangersign[1][2ex]{%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \scaleto{\stackon[1.3pt]{\color{red}$\triangle$}{\tiny !}}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a danger sign 5ex tall: \dangersign[5ex]\par
Here is the default (2ex) size: \dangersign
\end{document}
```

Zoom of result, to clarify my response to Charles' comment.

[image]

If one prefers a bolder `!`, just make it `\bfseries`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\dangersign[1][2ex]{%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \scaleto{\stackon[1.3pt]{\color{red}$\triangle$}{\tiny\bfseries !}}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a danger sign 5ex tall: \dangersign[5ex]\par
Here is the default (2ex) size: \dangersign
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's my imagination, but the exclamation point in the small version looks slightly off-center.

Comment: @CharlesStaats  Sometimes, when glyphs are overlaid, inexact rendering will make them appear off center.  Zooming in reveals a better approximation, and the printed result is accurate.  Zooming the small symbol to 6400% reveals aligned glyphs.

Comment: A question about the `stackrel` package: why does it render the `\danger` symbol from the `fourier` package as a letter `B`?

Comment: @CharlesStaats Do you mean `scalerel` package?  I would note that `scalerel` macros process their argument in math mode, by default, and one must actually delimit them with `$...$` to process in text mode.  So my guess is that the symbol is being processed in the wrong mode.

Comment: Your guess seems to have been entirely correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

When you use *XeLaTeX* or *LuaLaTeX* you can simply use the character as is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIXGeneral}
\newcommand\warningsign{⚠}
\begin{document}
    \warningsign Warning
\end{document}
```

Of course the font must contain it. (STIX does.)

It looks like this:

[image: Warning sign]

Notice that it is more common to give unicode code points in hexadecimal, here `U+26A0`.

If you don’t want to have unusual characters in your source code, you can specify the warning sign by its code point:

```
\newcommand\warningsign{\symbol{"26A0}}
```

(Found at “[How do I enter an arbitrary Unicode code point into my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/how-do-i-enter-an-arbitrary-unicode-code-point-into-my-document)”)

Comment: With the most recent version of the STIX fonts, the call should be `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIX}`

Comment: I appreciate the information, but prefer that my source code contain no characters that do not show up on my (American) keyboard.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: You can use ASCII characters: `^^^^26a0`, see [The `^^` notation in various engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62725/16967)

Answer (score 13):

The package `fontawesome` provides the commands `\faWarning` (equiv., `\faExclamationTriangle` for the warning icon, which looks like this:

[image]

A minimal example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\faWarning\, Warning: This product contains peanuts, %
which might not be very suitable for certain individuals.

\end{document}
```

The `fontawesome` package might be new, but it provides a wide range of high-quality web icons, and that makes it pretty relevant tool in terms of modern typesetting and design.

Comment: I couldn't find a better package for this kind of symbol

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\danger[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex, inner xsep=0pt,#1]
\node[]{$\triangle$};
\node[yshift=0.125ex, scale=0.45]{!};
\end{tikzpicture}\space}

A danger-sing \danger is shown here.

\huge A danger-sing \danger[red] is shown here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: sing?   did you mean "sign"?

Comment: Also the OP explicitly asked for a solution using a character, and "not done using graphics"

Comment: Yes, sign - I misspelled :(