# color - background for warning symbol

Tags: icon

This warning icon in link: [How to print a warning sign (triangle with exclamation point)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159669/how-to-print-a-warning-sign-triangle-with-exclamation-point)

i want to fill red colour in backgroud like attached image
[image]

This minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\dangersign[1][2ex]{%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \scaleto{\stackon[1.3pt]{\color{red}$\triangle$}{\tiny !}}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a danger sign 5ex tall: \dangersign[5ex]\par
Here is the default (2ex) size: \dangersign
\end{document}
```

! can black or white
Please help.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor,amssymb}
\newcommand\dangersignb[1][2ex]{%
  \scaleto{\stackengine{0.3pt}{\scalebox{1.1}[.9]{%
  \color{red}$\blacktriangle$}}{\tiny\bfseries !}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\dangersignw[1][2ex]{%
  \scaleto{\stackengine{0.3pt}{\scalebox{1.1}[.9]{%
  \color{red}$\blacktriangle$}}{\color{white}\tiny\bfseries !}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
This is a (black) danger sign 5ex tall: \dangersignb[5ex]\par
Here is the default (2ex) size: \dangersignb

This is a (white) danger sign 5ex tall: \dangersignw[5ex]\par
Here is the default (2ex) size: \dangersignw
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: B.Segletes. Your above code work in overleaf. But  I run in texmarker this come error: "package stackengine could not be installed". please help. thanks

Comment: @latexforti I am not familiar with texmarker, but you can find the style file at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine and place it in your working directory.

Comment: i embeded your code in my file. But warning icon https://imgur.com/xIGODZA : ! outside of the box. Can you center "!" symbol? Thanks

Comment: @latexforti I am not sure why the result is as you show.  The vertical placement of the `!` is controlled by the length `0.3pt` shown in my macro (try increasing it).  The stretched shape of the triangle is controlled by the scale number `[.9]` shown in my macro (try decreasing it).