# Up and down icon: set slightly below or above the normal line

Tags: icon

i want to set some icon appear below or above the baseline like attached image. And  it can change vertical space (mm, pt)

Minimal code from [color - background for warning symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483162/color-background-for-warning-symbol/483175?noredirect=1#comment1221964_483175)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor,amssymb}
\newcommand\dangersignb[1][2ex]{%
  \scaleto{\stackengine{0.3pt}{\scalebox{1.1}[.9]{%
  \color{red}$\blacktriangle$}}{\tiny\bfseries !}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
line: \dangersignb[5ex] Up \dangersignb[5ex] Down \dangersignb[5ex] 

\end{document}
```

Thank so much
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{xcolor,amssymb}
\newcommand\dangersignb[1][2ex]{%
  \scaleto{\stackengine{0.3pt}{\scalebox{1.1}[.9]{%
  \color{red}$\blacktriangle$}}{\tiny\bfseries !}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
line: \dangersignb[5ex] Up \dangersignb[5ex] Down \dangersignb[5ex] 

line: \dangersignb[5ex] Up \raisebox{1ex}{\dangersignb[5ex]} Down \raisebox{-1ex}{\dangersignb[5ex]} 

\end{document}
```

[image]