# Hyphenation Problem with german

Tags: babel, hyphenation, german

i have a problem with hyphenation and i could not find a solution.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage{cite}

\hyphenation{(Web"~)""Frame"-works}
```

The error message is:

> Description    Path    Resource    Location    Type
>   Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. \hyphenation{(Web"~ (followed by: )""Frame"-works})  line 84 Texlipse Build Error
>   Description Path    Resource    Location    Type
>   Not a letter. \hyphenation{( (followed by: Web"~)""Frame"-works}) line 84   Texlipse Build Error
>   I think the problem is the charackter ")"

Edit:

Thanks for all answers:

First i want to achieve the example here: http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_Silbentrennung
"~ : Mit dieser Anweisung setzt man einen Bindestrich, an dem nicht getrennt werden soll, beispielsweise bei Wortergänzungen in Klammern: (Haupt"~)""Straße
The \hyphenation (Web-)Framework should prevent hyphenation (Web-). Example (Web-

)Framwork is wrong.
I know the parenthesis aren't letters for TEX, but see the example it works. So I wonder what is wrong.

So here is the example:

```
\documentclass[
   11pt,                % Schriftgroesse 12pt
   a4paper,             % Layout fuer Din A4
   ngerman,             % deutsche Sprache, global
   oneside,            % einseitig
   headinclude,         % Kopfzeile wird Seiten-Layouts mit beruecksichtigt
   BCOR12mm,            % Korrektur fuer die Bindung
   DIV14,               % DIV-Wert fuer die Erstellung des Satzspiegels, siehe scrguide
   fleqn,               % fleqn: Glgen links (statt mittig)
   %draft,               % Keine Bilder in der Anzeige, overfull hboxes werden angezeigt
   appendixprefix,              %berschriften des Anhangs +"Anhang"
  %chapterprefix,               %berschriften der Kapitel +"KAPITEL"
   abstracton,
   pdftex                       %Ueberschrift Zusammenfassung einschalten
     ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}
\selectlanguage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\hyphenation{(Web"~)""Frame"-works}  
\begin{document}
(Web-)Frameworks asdasd (Web-)Frameworks asd (Web-)Frameworks (Web-)Frameworks
(Web-)Frameworks asdsada (Web-)Frameworks asd (Web-)Frameworks (Web-)Frameworks
(Web-)Frameworks asdasdasd (Web-)Frameworks (Web-)Frameworks (Web-)Frameworks
(Web-)Frameworks asdasdas (Web-)Frameworks (Web-)Frameworks
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm a german, please add a minimal working example I can copy on my computer and play with it. Then I can help you.

Comment: By the way, you can drop option `german` and hence the next line. There is absolutely no use in it.

Comment: The parenthesis aren't letters for TeX. `! Not a letter.
l.8 \hyphenation{(
                  Web"~)""Frame"-works}
? ! Not a letter.
l.8 \hyphenation{(Web"
                      ~)""Frame"-works}
` Hence the problem. But, as a fellow german, i don't know what you are trying to do. Do you want to prevent hyphenation there?

Comment: You can only have words in `\hyphenation` not markup, what effect are you trying to specify?

Comment: Please augment your code snippets to form a compilable example that generates the problem at hand. Please also state which TeX distribution you use. I suppose we can guess that you're using TeXclipse as the front-end...

Comment: the required pattern for `\hyphenation` allows only letters, embedded hyphens, and spaces to separate words.  you *could* accomplish what it looks like you want with this definition: `\newcommand{\WFw}{(Web)~Frame\-works}`.  (i don't think you really mean you want a space before the parenthesis.)  there are other variations, but your description isn't really clear.

Comment: `(Web"~)""Frame"-works` looks like usage of `babel` shorthands in the text – this is surely not meant for usage in `\hyphenation`

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96339/hyphenation-next-to-a-parenthesis

Answer (score 6):

In the argument to `\hyphenation` only letters and hyphens to mark the admissible break points are allowed; `babel` shortcuts are definitely not allowed.

The simplest strategy for coping with this problem is to define a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newcommand{\WFW}{(Web\mbox{-})\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}Framework}
\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{frame-work frame-works}

\begin{document}

\WFW{} asdasd \WFW{} asd \WFW{} \WFW{}
\WFW{} asdsada \WFW{} asd \WFW{} \WFW{}
\WFW{} asdasdasd \WFW{} \WFW{} \WFW s
\WFW s asdasdas \WFW s \WFW s

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the command you can surely type the word as

```
(Web"~)""Framework
```

in your document and, thanks to the `\babelhyphen` declarations, hyphenation would only be `Frame-work` or `Frame-works` with a possible break after the parenthesis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{frame-work frame-works}

\begin{document}

(Web"~)""Framework asdasd (Web"~)""Framework asd (Web"~)""Framework (Web"~)""Framework
(Web"~)""Framework asdsada (Web"~)""Framework asd (Web"~)""Framework (Web"~)""Framework
(Web"~)""Framework asdasdasd (Web"~)""Framework (Web"~)""Framework (Web"~)""Frameworks
(Web"~)""Frameworks asdasdas (Web"~)""Frameworks (Web"~)""Frameworks

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define a new command like as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\babelhyphenation[ngerman]{frame-work frame-works}

\shorthandon{"}
\newcommand{\WEB}{(Web"~)""}
\shorthandoff{"}

\begin{document}

(Web"~)""Framework asdasd (Web"~)""Framework asd (Web"~)""Framework (Web"~)""Framework
(Web"~)""Framework asdsada (Web"~)""Framework asd (Web"~)""Framework (Web"~)""Framework
(Web"~)""Framework asdasdasd (Web"~)""Framework (Web"~)""Framework (Web"~)""Frameworks
(Web"~)""Frameworks asdasdas (Web"~)""Frameworks (Web"~)""Frameworks

\WEB Framework asdasd \WEB Framework asd \WEB Framework \WEB Framework
\WEB Framework asdsada \WEB Framework asd \WEB Framework \WEB Framework
\WEB Framework asdasdasd \WEB Framework \WEB Framework \WEB Frameworks
\WEB Frameworks asdasdas \WEB Frameworks \WEB Frameworks

\end{document}
```

Alternatively,

```
\shorthandon{"}
\newcommand{\WEB}[1]{(Web"~)""#1}
\shorthandoff{"}
```

but the input should be `\WEB{Framework}`. Take your pick.

This is the output of the above example.

[image]

Comment: I know the possibility for new commands but this not what iam looking for. Why does the example work with (Haupt"~)""Straße

Comment: @Michael Surely not. If I try `\hyphenation{(Haupt"~)""Straße}` I get an error message; but even if this weren't the case, the command would have no consequence in the hyphenation, because it's given when the language is not yet set to `ngerman`.

Comment: @Michael I added a different strategy.

Comment: you are right :(

Of course the second strategy will work, but a global definition would be nice.

So if i want to use (Web"~)""Frame"-works, i have to use commands?

Comment: @Michael Yes, but you don't need the `"-` in the middle of `Frameworks` if you use the `\babelhyphen` command I suggest.

Comment: Ok i add a new command \newcommand{\WEB}[1]{(Web"=)""{#1}} it's not so nice but when there is no better solution.

Comment: @Michael I'll add a couple of alternatives.

Comment: thanks for your help. But without command it's very awkward. There is no possibility to use just the word (Web-)Framework and tex will do the hyphenation right.

Comment: @Michael No, sorry.

Comment: ok, so i think the combination with a new command and babelhyphenation is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

```
\newunicodechar{‑}{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\symbol{'177}}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

Then just use ‑ (U+2011) instead of - (U+002D) before the closing parenthesis. This means you can now write `(re‑)creation` or `(Web‑)Frameworks` or even `Entwicklungs‑, Test/QS‑, Staging‑ oder Produktivsystem` (yes, I got dash-comma working).

If this does not work for you, @dessert reports that a combination of this and [Dmitry’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283196/43807) works:

```
\newunicodechar{‑}{\babelhyphen{nobreak}}
```

Which one to use seems to depend on the version of `babel` you use, and how you use it.

### Backstory

I was looking for this as well, but as a more generic solution, and so far, the answers I found all do not satisfy me. I do have the german Babel package included, but `"~` just typeset a double-quote followed by a space for me (and, in fact, I think I prefer double quotes to render as quote characters).

I looked at Unicode, and ‑ `U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN` appears to be what I want. Apparently, Xe(La)TeX already supports this, but we use pdflatex (directly in one project, via maven-latex-plugin in another), so that was out.

This pointed me into the correct direction though: I [already knew about `\newunicodechar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159701/43807) so I thought I could just make U+2011 available. My first attempt was…

```
% does not work
\newunicodechar{‑}{-}
```

… to just define it to the hyphen, but it does not work like that. So, after reading some answers here, I tried…

```
% throws an error message
\newunicodechar{‑}{\nobreakdash-\hspace{0pt}}
```

… but `\nobreakdash` is not known, apparently. Finally, I tried…

```
% works for me, except commas
\newunicodechar{‑}{-\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

… and voilà, I can typeset “(Maschinen‑)Benutzernamen” without the ugly separation *and* the automatic hyphenation makes this into “(Maschinen-)Benut-⏎zernamen” which is just perfect. Even better, when copy/pasting from the PDF, you get an actual - `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS`, which makes things like `\texttt{<!‑‑}` to get `<!--` (for XML comments) work.

#### Update 2016-09-04: Commas

There was a problem though: `‑,` would still shove the stray comma onto the next line. The [explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268859/43807) has to do with us still using the `-` ASCII hyphen-minus in our macro expansion, to which Teχ (un‑)helpfully adds a discretionary break. However, this can be worked around if the current font has a T1 encoding (and not just OT1 or LY1), by temporarily switching to the T1 encoding variant of the current font and outputting the named character 127 (0x7F), which is exactly the same as the standard \hyphenchar 45 (0x2D).

```
% works for me
\newunicodechar{‑}{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\symbol{'177}}\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}}
```

For the (custom TrueType) font I was using, this required [some hacking](https://evolvis.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=veraweb/veraweb.git;a=commitdiff;h=ed3bc31b06c6e5c834f2d0460304405422f5f177;hp=1512ba84120fe71274212a49a568b3e53ccf3651) due to [a ttf2tfm bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=836691); if you just want to make sure that your font’s T1 encoding has the correct glyph at the correct position, use this (and replace `museo` with your font name):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\xfonttable{T1}{museo}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

(Note: I merged my answers to several questions in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282420/43807) then copied it to these other questions, so don’t wonder if it shows up in three places.)

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}

\shorthandon{"}
\newcommand\WFW{(Web"~)""Frameworks\xspace}
\hyphenation{Frame-works}% to prevent Fra-me-works
\begin{document}
\noindent
    \WFW asdsad \WFW asssda \WFW \WFW
    \WFW asdsada \WFW asd \WFW \WFW
    \WFW asdasdasd \WFW sss \WFW fff \WFW
    \WFW asdasdas \WFW \WFW
\end{document}
```