# What is the difference between "-" and "--" in text mode?

Tags: symbols, punctuation, text-mode

I'm interested in all the difference, that means:

- appearance: If there are common rules across fonts like distance from baseline, length and so on.
- typographical rules: If they are handled differently when the compiler chooses where to break lines/pages.
- semantically: The meaning of them, that is also when I'm supposed to use them.

Googling it I've found that exist a lot of similar glyph, even if I never seen them in any LaTeX document. Some of them - all usable in text mode without external packages - are: `\--`, `\---`, `\----`, `\textendash`, `\textemdash`. So if you want to expand your answer you could also clarify what are those symbols and when they should be used.

Comment: The typographic rules for using these symbols vary by language. Which language, or languages, do you employ in your documents?

Comment: The common rules across fonts normally are that `-` (hyphen) is the shortest, followed by an en-dash `--`/`\textenmdash` (you'd expect it to be one en long, [one en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_(typography)) is half an em), the longest of the three is an em-dash `---`/`\textemdash` (one em long, [one em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)) was traditionally the width of the capital M). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Comment: In Latin modern the hyphen is visibly thicker and lower than en-dash and em-dash. In Linux Libertine the general tendency is the same, but less noticeable. With `mathpazo` all characters are roughly at the same height, but the hyphen is still a tad thicker. There is a difference between `--` and `\--` as well as `---` and `\---`. You'll definitely want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3819/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103608/35864. The semantics and common use depend on the language.

Comment: @Mico, usually English and Italian.

Comment: @moewe, your comment could be an answer. Also, I think that you identified my question as a duplicate. I swear that I searched for an answer but I didn't get it, probably because `-` is a special character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `-`   generates a hyphen (aka ‘dash’)
- `--`  generates an en-dash
- `---` generates an em-dash
- `$-$` generates a minus sign (in math mode)

A hyphen is the shortest, an em-dash is the longest.

- Hyphens are used for compound words like ‘daughter-in-law’ and ‘X-ray’. Hyphens are also use to break up a long word at the end of a line within a paragraph.
- En-dashes are used for number ranges like ‘pages 13–34’, and also in contexts like ‘exercise 1.2.6–52’.
- Em-dashes are used for punctuation in sentences—they are what we often call simply dashes.

(The TeXbook, page 4)

In German I would use `~--`  (a non-breaking space followed by an en-dash followed by a normal space) instead of `---` as a dash.

I would assume that `\textendash` is equivalent to `--` and `\textemdash` to `---`.

`\-` is defined as `\discretionary{-}{}{}`. It generates a hyphen if it is at the end of a line or nothing otherwise.
Please note that words containing a discretionary are ignored by TeX's automatic hyphenation algorithm. (The TeXbook, pages 95–96)

`\--`, `\---` and `\----` are *not* standard LaTeX. They appear to be defined by the [extdash package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/doc/extdash.pdf), see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283202/120953) (thanks to moewe for the link in the comments).

Comment: you might add joint-author references, as in "the Birch--Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture", to the uses for the en-dash (two authors there, Birch, and the already-hyphenated Swinnerton-Dyer).  and you may as well add `\-` (the discretionary hyphen) just to be exhaustively complete.