# How to prevent hyphenation of words that has hyphen?

Tags: hyphenation

How can I prevent the hyphenation of words with hyphens?

For example: `Wi-Fi`, `F-1`

Is it possible to add the exceptions to `\hyphenation`?

Comment: [how to force latex not to break the line after a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103608/how-to-force-latex-not-to-break-the-line-after-a-hyphen)