# Spacing in "$d=2$-dimensional"

Tags: spacing, typography, mathematics

What is the correct spacing if I want to write phrases like "d=3-dimensional".

If I just write `$d=1$-dimensional`, the spacing around the equal-sign seems to be way too wide for me?

[image]

(Maybe also the spacing around the "-" could be a little bit too small?)

(I want to use this formulation to subtly remind the reader that the input dimension is called `$d$` in this text, while telling that the current sections only deals with the 1-dimensional case.)

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
Define a neural network $\mathcal{NN}_\theta$ as a function from $X=\R^d$ to $Y=\R$ s.t.

\[
\mathcal{NN}_\theta (x)=\dots defintion \dots \quad\forall x\in X
\]

For the rest of the section only the the $d=1$-dimensional case is considered.
\end{document}
```

(PS: Probably one should also add something against hyphenation, like mentioned here: [Avoid hyphenation in "2-D"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9691/avoid-hyphenation-in-2-d). It would be nice if this were already included in the answer.)

Comment: It's probably because you're writing `$d = 1$-dimensional`, which psychologically leaves the `1` separated from `dimensional`. How about `$d = \text{$1$-dimensional}$`. It'll look the same, but you'll feel better about it. ;) You can also just write it out: `$d$ is $1$-dimensional`.

Comment: Nice approach the "is" instead of `$=$` because if you use `$=$` in math .. you could always replace the first (or the second) part of that equity with the other part everywhere that can be found (in math)...And in this "equation" this could cause "funny results". So, is should be the solution as you suggested (@Werner) .

Comment: @Werner I want to express that $x\in\R^d$ is d-dimensional. I don't want to express that the natural number d is d-dimensional

Comment: @koleygr I actually want to express that the dimension d=1 is equal to one within this section. Thus everywhere in this section one could replace d by one or the other way around.

Comment: `$d=1$ where $d$ is the number of dimensions` [... and thus we have a `1-dimensional` ... (motion or something)] or `If we name $d$ the number of dimensions we have...` (Just realized that used my Greek approach in this second sentence... Usually in English scientific/tutoring formal texts "we don't use 'we' ")

Comment: To suppress line-breaking after the hyphen, `amsmath` provides the command `\nobreakdash`.  See p.14 of the `amsmath` user guide (`texdoc amsmath`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Please see the answer I posted a few seconds after you posted your comment. :-)

Comment: I feel like `$d=1$-dimensional` isn't grammatical to begin with, and that reflects itself in your typesetting difficulties.  (Also not that the first two comments misinterpreted your intent, which suggests that your notation isn't intuitive.)  An equation is grammatically a sentence, which can't modify "dimensional".  I would recommend "Within this section, $d=1$."

Comment: "For the rest of this section only the case of dimension $d=1$ is considered."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on @Mico's code, with the help of `xparse`, I propose  a `\Diml` command, in which the spacing around the = sign is tighter, and the argument is input in a more natural way, as d = some value. It is of course easy to adjust the spacing to your taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\Diml}[1]{\dimlargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dimlargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{=}}m}
{\dimlargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dimlargsaux}{mm}{%
 \text{$ #1\mkern2mu{=}\mkern2mu#2 $\nobreakdash-dimensional}}%

\begin{document}

$\Diml{d=1},\;\Diml{e = n }$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This post fits my personal taste, but I would be interested in some comments if this is good typography? Ideally some references how other authors use this notation? Is this notation easily understandable or should I switch to other formulations like "only the case of dimension $d=1$ is considered" (by @Andrew Swann) or "in the case of  input dimension $d=1$ ..."?

Comment: Good typography is the art of making things easy to read. I have no particular references, albeit I've often met this way of formulating things – it's a sort of usual ellipsis, but I guess most authors don't care about the exact spacing – they're mathematicians, after all, not typographers, and they trust TeX to do the job.

Comment: It would be really nice to extend your code to phrases like "d-1-dimensional sphere". At the moment I am writing `$ d\mkern0mu{-}\mkern0mu1 $\nobreakdash-dimensional` manually every time I speak of a lower dimensional sphere or subspace

Comment: I have added a more general question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517425/coorect-spacing-in-math-inside-a-word

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've loaded the `amsmath` package, I would make use of its `\nobreakdash` directive to make sure there's never a line break between `2-` and `dimensional`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \nobreakdash and \text macros
%% Define a macro that takes an optional argument;
%% default value of optional argument is '2'.
\newcommand\diml[1][2]{\text{$#1$\nobreakdash-dimensional}}

\begin{document}
$d=\diml$, $d=\diml[3]$, $d=\diml[n]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: is this good spacing? I would have expected the preferable spacing to be much narrower around the "="?

Comment: @Jakob - The spacing around the `=` symbo in question is exactly the same as around all other `=` symbols in text-style and display-style math mode. You'll automatically get less spacing when in script-style and scriptscript-style math mode.

Comment: In this case I’d agree with @Jakob that it is much too much space. With the current spacing it could easily be read as “the variable _d_ equals the string _2-dimensional_” instead of a single word _d-two-dimensional_. Thus I’d narrow the spacing around the `=` down to nearly zero. However it might be even better to find a different notation for this. Maybe something like _2-dimensional (d=2)_